# Cucumber видит step definitions из одного файла, но не видит из другого

Tags: java, test-automation, cucumber

Написал простой UI тест, состоящий из:

- feature файла
- somePage (page object некоторой страницы)
- someSteps (step definitions).

Наглядная иерархия:

```
src
--test
  --java
   --tests
      --pages
        --somePage
          --SomePage.class
          --SomeSteps.class
        --RunnerTest.class
  --resources
    --features
      --some.feature
```

В раннере указал features и glue. Всё работало.

Потом я добавил второй feature файл, для которого я также создал файлы со степами, добавил его в glue. Но при запуске выяснилось, что все шаги из нового фича-файла выдают "Steps Undefined".
Intellij IDEA видит реализацию шагов, по ним можно перейти из фича-файла в класс, но при запуске (Ctrl+Shift+F10) получаю неизменный "Steps Undefined".
Первая фича по-прежнему работает.

Совершенно не понимаю, куда копать. Структура реализации первой и второй фичи абсолютно идентична.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

У меня была похожая проблема, решила ее с помощью импорта Given из пакета io.cucumber.java.en.Given;